# ST3 snippet: trigger HTML snippet but not on PHP scope

Tags: sublimetext, code-snippets, sublimetext3

**PHP:**

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
foreach (\$${1} as \$${2:k}=>\$${3:v}) {
    ${4}
}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>fore</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

**HTML (and on .php files with html)**

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<?php foreach (\$${1} as \$${2:k}=>\$${3:v}) : ?>
    ${4}
<?php endforeach; ?>
</script>
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>fore</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.html, text.html.basic</scope>
</snippet>
```

how can I enable "*text.html.basic*" on the second snippet without making it trigger when I'm on a PHP file, since it's also "*text.html.basic source.php.%*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: you have an excess (as I persume) `</script>` ending tag in HTML snippet.

What you have to do is this:

#### HTML

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<?php foreach (\$${1} as \$${2:k}=>\$${3:v}) : ?>
    ${4}
<?php endforeach; ?>
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>fore</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html - source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

#### PHP

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
foreach (\$${1} as \$${2:k}=>\$${3:v}) {
    ${4}
}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>fore</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

As you may see, the HTML snippet negates the `source.php` scope with a `-` (minus) sign

Comment: Doesn't matter! Accepting is enough! Welcome to SO!